# mysqli_query, mysqli_fetch_array and while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and I am trying to build a website using PHP. I have localhost for testing the result and I have phpmyadmin already installed on the website.

What i am trying to do now, is to list the contents of my table "property" from database "portal" and fill a table with the results.

I am using `mysqli_query`, `mysqli_fetch_array` and while loop. I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\falcon\portal\forms\edit listing.php
>   on line 15

```
session_start();
require_once "connect_to_mysql.php"; // where i store username and password to access    my db.

$sqlCommand = "SELECT * property FROM portal"; // dbname: portal - table: propery
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand);

$Displayproperty = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
$id = $row["pid"];
$title = $row["ptitle"];
$area = $row["parea"];
$city = $row["pcity"];
$Displayproperty .= '<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
<tr>
<td>' . $id . '</td>
<td>' . $title . '</td>
<td>' . $area . '</td>
<td>' . $city . '</td>
<td><a href="forms.php?pid=' . $id . '">Upload images</a><br /></td>
</tr>
</table>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your query with this. Make sure you have added this line before.

```
$db = mysql_select_db('portal');

$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM property";
```

Comment: Thanks. The error has disappeared but I am not getting any data displayed.

Comment: Good. After the query, immediately type this line and check how many rows you get.

echo $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($query);

Comment: Also you dont have curly brackets after while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)). It should be while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { and then end it after table tag, </table>'; }

Comment: I'm getting an error "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in".

Comment: I have the curly brackets added.

Answer (score 4):

Your query is wrong, so after

```
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand);
```

$query is false. That's why, you get the error.

The correct SQL Query is:

```
SELECT * FROM portal.property
```

If you need to specify the database name.
Also, before doing:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
```

You should check that $query exists

```
if(!empty($query) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM portal.property"; /* Database_Name.Table_Name */
```

Or simply use

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM property";
```

Comment: You mean `portal.property` :-P

Comment: table "property" from database "portal".. isn't it other way around

Comment: @RocketHazmat haha that was confusing thnx :p

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a syntax error in your SQL statement, which is causing `mysqli_query()` to return false.

`SELECT * property FROM portal` is not valid SQL.

You should always check to make sure mysqli_query returns a valid result with a construct like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand);
if(! $result) {
    die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($myConnection));
}

// use result here.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement

```
SELECT * property FROM portal
```

is not correct sql, therefore the query doesn't get executed. Try removing the word  `property` to get some results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first connect to DB portal using:

```
$myConnection = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

Then run:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM property"); // This will run the query on portal database.
```

If you want to simply query property table of portal you can use:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM portal.property");
```

or

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM portal.property");
```